# ADO.NET connection to Oracle in SSIS package hangs but doesn't time out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, ssis, ado.net

An ADO.NET connection to Oracle in a SSIS package 'hangs' but doesn't time out - i.e. the progress of the package seems to halt when an attempt at a connection to Oracle is made but never times out with an error. Logging stops just after a couple of initial housekeeping activities on the SQL Server destination but no further logging associated with the connection to, and data extract from, Oracle is apparent. The package will then continue doing nothing unless it is stopped manually.

I'm certainly interested in what the problem might be but I'm also looking for suggestions for a better solution than the one I have in place at the moment. This is a SQL Agent admin job that checks the duration of the job running the SSIS package and, if it's been running for over 3 hours - it never runs for more than 3 hours normally - then the admin job stops and re-starts it.

The Oracle source is 11g, the SQL Server destination and SSIS host is 2008 R2 SP2 and the SSIS development environment is Visual Studio 2008.

Gordon.

Comment: Sounds strange. Did you specify any "Command timeout" in the properties of your source? Another idea might be to check out a third party component - such as the Attunity source.

Comment: Yes, the timeout is 30 seconds on the connection string however it seems to have no effect under these circumstances. Will check out Attunity though, thanks.